# informatica live data map(LDM) installation

Tags: informatica

We are facing the issue while starting the informatica cluster service.

When starting Informatica cluster services, some scripts installing Ambari server on infabde, bdemaster and bdeslave.

The script is trying to install ambari on infabde again and again in loop, So the cluster service failed to start by saying that `Ambari already installed in infabde`. Its not trying to install to other two nodes.

Error Log:

```
2017-01-12 17:10:30,763 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  com.infa.products.ihs.service.ambari.ScriptLauncher- Waiting for Script's streams to end.
2017-01-12 17:10:41,210 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR com.infa.products.ihs.beans.application.ClusterListener- [InfaHadoopServiceException_00047] The launch of Ambari server on host [infabde.lucidtechsol.com] failed because the host already has an installed Ambari server. You can add the host to another cluster.
com.infa.products.ihs.service.exception.InfaHadoopServiceException: [InfaHadoopServiceException_00047] The launch of Ambari server on host [infabde.hostname.com] failed because the host already has an installed Ambari server. You can add the host to another cluster.
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! To get the most out of the site it is important to ask good questions. A guide to asking questions is at: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Do you have programming question? For example, are you writing the installation scripts and need help with them?  If not, this question is likely off -topic for SO.

Answer (score 0):

Run the reset script

./ResetScript.sh true user@server.com user@server.com

./ResetScript.sh false user@server.com user@client.com

and enable IHS then.

ResetScript.sh can be found in services/Infahadoopserveice/binaries